Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus compatible with azure functions v1?
We were planning to upgrade the Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging to the latest version but we were facing issues as NuGet was telling to update to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.

Source
After doing so I am getting something like this:

using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
//using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration;
using Model.Export;
using Model.Export.Enum;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using Utility.Export;

namespace AzureFunctions.Export
{
    public static class ExportDataProcessor
    {
        [FunctionName("ExportDataProcessor")]
        public static async void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%ExportQueueName%", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]string busData, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext context)

My csproj contains:

So in order to use  Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus do I need to update my version of Azure Functions?
Also what would you recommend in case I upgrade?

Can you share your code in text formate?

Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus is compatible with Azure Functions v2 and later, but not with Azure Functions v1. To use Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, you would indeed need to update your Azure Functions runtime to v2 or later.

Even I received the same error as yours because AccessRights enum is still available in Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging, it's worth noting that the related classes like MessagingFactory are deprecated. If you're utilizing AccessRights within your ServiceBusTrigger attribute, it might be advisable to stick with Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging for the time being. In case you opt to transition to Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, remember that you'll need to adjust your ServiceBusTrigger attribute to employ classes from the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus package.
I updated my Azure function's v1 ServiceBusTrigger attribute and namespace like below:-
Function1.cs:-
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

namespace FunctionApp10
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "conn")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}

Function.csproj:-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v1</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.17.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Output:-

Alternatively,  You can migrate your Function from v1 to v4 which is the latest Function extension or v1 to v3 and utilize  Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus and  Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus to make your Function app service bus queue trigger work.
